# NavigationView: one icon isn't tinting but the rest are. How to tint it?

Tags: android, icons, navigation-drawer

**Update:** Found a related bug report. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176133  I upgraded my support libraries to 23.3.0, but it didn't fix the problem.

**Update:** If I change the icon, then it works. Something isn't working with this message icon.

I have a navigation drawer, and every item is tinting except one. It is using the default settings. They are all tinting to "colorPrimary" when they are selected, except for messaging.  How do I get the Messaging icon to also tint?

Correctly tinting icon:

[image]

Not tinting this icon though:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:id="@+id/nav_group_sections"
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24d"
            android:title="@string/home"
            android:checked="true" /> <!-- default selection -->
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_tools_black_24d"
            android:title="@string/tools" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_web"
            android:title="@string/web"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_link_black_24dp"
            android:visible="false"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_messaging"
            android:title="@string/messaging"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_message_black_24dp"
            />
    </group>
</menu>
```

The icons are these:

[image]
[image]